# Where do the Shoal sit?

Tags: doctor-who, aliens

(Warning: spoilers. Not going to put the whole thing in spoiler tags.)

I call them the Shoal; they probably have another name, but not one I'm aware of.

In *The Return of Doctor Mysterio*, they are depicted as brains, or, rather, brain shaped aliens, who have a habit of cutting people open, removing their brains and putting themselves in.

Near the beginning, Mr Brocks says looking at one of them, "It's got the same eyes as you" (indicating Dr. Sims who has already undergone the procedure). So obviously the alien brain sits in the same space as our own brain would. Otherwise the position of the eyes wouldn't fit.
However, we see later that the heads of such people can split open down the middle and can be used as a storage locker, for guns and stuff.

So where do the Shoal actually sit? They don't take up all the available space in the head? Are they deflatable? Do they themselves split down the middle when someone opens their head? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It isn't remarked on in the episode. They must either [Krang](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/e/ec/Krang's_robot.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110225161210) it up (and the eyes are some kind of technology), or use a compression field (like the Slitheen or the pilots of the time traveling shape shifting robot powered by tiny people).

Answer (score 1):

Our nervous system isn't only in our brain, it's also in our spinal cord:

[image]

I'm just speculating here, but the [Shoal](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/profiles/48hxN3HMVPSzTHjvWyprB0s/the-brains-and-harmony-shoal) might be able to change their shape, keeping their *eyes* in the cranium, and squeezing the rest into the spinal cord. I'm assuming this because the Doctor calls them (emphasis mine)

> Multi-nucleate organism, functioning as an **infinitely adaptable**, independently functioning, peripatetic **central nervous system**.
>
> <sub>Doctor Who: The Return of Doctor Mysterio</sub>

The fact that they're adaptable, and not just brains, but a full nervous system, is what I'm basing this speculation upon.